# How to get this project to pause for the given amount of time after the button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, timer, delay

So, I am trying to figure out how to add pauses in my card game to make the CPU act like they are taking turns. But, there's too much code involved, so I think if we demonstrate the strategy on this code, it could work.

How can I make this code pause for, say 5 seconds after the button has been pushed and THEN print the message.

```
public class TimerTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7416567620110237028L;
JTextArea area;
Timer timer;
int count; // Counts the number of sendings done by the timer
boolean running; // Indicates if the timer is started (true) or stopped (false)

public TimerTest() {
    super("Test");
    setBounds(30,30,500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);

    area = new JTextArea();
    area.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 400);
    add(area);

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setBounds(200, 400, 100, 40);
    add(button);

    // Initialization of the timer. 1 second delay and this class as ActionListener
    timer = new Timer(5000, this);
    timer.setRepeats(true); // Send events until someone stops it
    count = 0; // in the beginning, 0 events sended by timer
    running = false;
    System.out.println(timer.isRepeats());
    setVisible(true); // Shows the frame
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (! running) {
        timer.start();
        running = true;
    }
    // Writing the current time and increasing the cont times
    area.append(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString()+"\n");
    count++;
    if (count == 10) {
        timer.stop();
        count = 0;
        running = false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Executing the frame with its Timer
    new TimerTest();
}
}
```

What I really would like to do is to be able to insert a pause into my method that runs the actions of each CPU. But it sounds like, with the Timer class, you need to perform your post-pause actions in the Timer's action listener. I am mostly confused about why the Timer needs an actionListener. I don't need the timer to repeat itself after it is done.

If it would be better for me to post my own code, let me know. But I am not sure what parts would be useful, since I don't want to have tons of code in this thread.

Comment: Try adding `Thread.sleep(5000);`?

Comment: What's wrong with the Swing `Timer`?  If you set it to non-repeating, with a delay of `5000`, it can call another method to perform what ever action you want AFTER the specified period of time?

Comment: @DarshanMehta You may not be aware the danger and issues associated with using `Thread.sleep` in Swing or JavaFX or just about any UI framework, it's not a good idea and for all the additional trouble it causes, you shouldn't recommend it, for this use case

Comment: You're going to want to do some investigation into layout managers, `null` layouts will cause you no end of issues and trouble

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, you want to trigger some event after 5 seconds, Swing `Timer` is perfect for this AND it's thread safe, making it safe to update the UI from, without the need for more hoop jumping.

The `Timer` sets up it's own thread to wait in, so it won't block the EDT, this means that you need to wait till the timer is triggered before you can something, it won't block and wait where you call it, this is the reason it has an `ActionListener`, so you know when it's triggered.

You can use your existing `Timer`, assuming it's not doing anything else, but for argument sake, I'm creating a new one...

```
private Timer waitItOut;
private JButton button;
```

Then in your constructor, you set up the timer, the difference here is I've made it non-repeating, meaning it won't trigger every 5 seconds, but you can re-run it when you want...

```
waitItOut = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        doImportantWork();
    }
});
waitItOut.setRepeats(false);

// I made this an instance field for demonstration purposes
button = new JButton("Click Me!");
button.addActionListener(this);
button.setBounds(200, 400, 100, 40);
add(button);
```

Then in your `actionPerformed` method, you simply start the timer...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    button.setEnabled(false);
    waitItOut.restart();
}
```

And wait till it calls your "important method which should be run after the specified delay"...

```
public void doImportantWork() {
    button.setEnabled(false);
    // Writing the current time and increasing the cont times
    area.append(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString()+"\n");
    count++;
    if (count == 10) {
        count = 0;
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this worked with the test program above! It will take me awhile to work this into my card game, but I will report the results when I figure it out.

Comment: @Austen Part of the solution is, you're going to need to change the way you are thinking, with GUIs, you can't think in a linear manner, they are event driven, something happens and you respond to it

Comment: So, it worked in my game. But, it turns out that I DO need to allow the timer to repeat. The way I have the CPU set up is that a for loop cycles through the remaining players until they get back to the user. I am trying to have the timer pause the actions of the CPUs after they draw a new card and before they make a play. But for some reason, it isn't restarting the timer in the next instance of the for loop. So it will get through player 2 and then stop at player 3. I am trying to debug with eclipse and it may actually just be my code, but I'm not sure

Comment: Update. It was because I tried to regulate the timer with a timerRunning boolean and since the timer was called again in the same thread, it didn't allow it to run again.

Answer (score 0):

You should launch a new thread which does the following:

- Sleep for 5 seconds
- Sets your required message
- Calls `repaint()` to signal that the message needs to be redrawn.

Comment: Swing is not Thread safe, the OP is using the appropriate Swing `Timer`, but just not using it correctly

Answer (score 0):

On a action performed situation, you can initiate certain functions like:
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
to do this. I see in your code that you are trying to manually count for time. You can let the compiler or cpu do this for you.

Comment: Swing is not Thread safe, the OP is using the appropriate Swing `Timer`, but just not using it correctly